Best practices for handling cascading deletes in NestJS application with MongoDB
Question in short
How do I best design a NestJS application with three models inside a hierarchy?
Detailed question
I am building a small Calendar service using Node, ExpressApp, NestJS and MongoDB. This is how my (simplified) data model looks like:
+------------------+         +------------------+         +------------------+
|    Calendar      |         |      Event       |         |   Invitation     |
+------------------+         +------------------+         +------------------+
| - _id            |         | - _id            |         | - _id            |
| - name           | 1 --- * | - calendar       | 1 --- * | - event          |
| - owner          |         | - description    |         | - email          |
+------------------+         | - date           |         +------------------+
                             | - visibility     |       
                             +------------------+

In SQL, the field calendar on the model Event would be a ForeignKey, but that is not available in MongoDB. Same for the field event on the model Invitation.
I used NestJS code generator to generate a CRUD app per model. This works fine individually, but the problem starts when I want to delete a Calendar and all its associated children. The standard delete operation inside CalendarService only deletes the Calendar object itself, but not its children. This has to be implemented manually. This can be done in the following ways:

The module Calendar is aware of its children. The EventService offers functionality to delete all Events from a given Calendar. The CalendarService calls this function. Similar for EventService calling InvitationService. The drawback I see here is that this might lead to circular dependencies. The logical dependency is that Event relies on Calendar, not vice versa.
The module Calendar sends out a Node event that a calendar is deleted, which is picked up by the module Event. The drawbacks I see is that you have to install and enable Node events, and that the impact of deleting a calendar is unclear, you have to follow all Node events.
Some kind of dependency injection into the CalendarService from the module Event. The drawback I see is that this is rather complex logic to just delete children of an object.
Place all models in a single module, and treat it as such. All Services have access to all models. The drawback I see with this is that in this particular case it's still feasible and manageable, but I am afraid this will quickly grow out of control.

I have found a lot of NestJS tutorials about resources, but they all include only a single resource, so this problem is never addressed. My question is: what is the best / most agreed on architecture to solve this seemingly simple problem?

Generally speaking, this depends on your data modeling and the canonical way to approach this in MongoDB is denormalizing the data. With a denormalized data model, you are not even required to handle the linkage between documents as everything is stored within the same document. This official document could be a good starting point to learn more about the topic.

In this particular case, a denormalized model for these models might make sense. But I feel that's mainly because it's a simplified example that I posted here. For instance, I have a similar problem if I delete an Organization (field owner on Calendar), after which all its calendars need to be deleted as well. You wouldn't add the calendars to the organization document, would you?

My initial thought would be nested documents like this as the event and invitation arrays' sizes seem manageable. You just need to delete the documents in collection calendar by owner for your use case of deletion

Or if the arrays are going to grow unbounded, you may store the information at invitation level and duplicating the parent Event and Calendar information like this
